# How to fix "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods, uncaught-exception

Below is the code am trying the figure out, when arrays (bill, tipValue, totalAmmount) are declared within the object method i get "cannot set property '0' undefined error. But, When the same arrays are declared outside the object then i get expected result"

**code am getting exception:**

```js
var john = {
    bill: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
    tipValue: [],
    totalAmmount: [],
    calcTip() {
        this.bill.forEach(function (ele, i) {
            this.tipValue[i] = innercalc(ele);
            this.totalAmmount[i] = this.tipValue[i] + ele;
        }); //not working code

        function innercalc(value) {
            if (value < 50)
                return value * 0.2;
            else if (value > 50 && value < 200)
                return value * 0.15;
            else if (value > 200)
                return value * 0.1;
        }
    }
}

john.calcTip();
console.log(john.tipValue);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
   
    <script src="codingchallange5.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Uncaught Exception: Cannot set Property '0' of undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jAMO1.png)

**Code which is working:**

```js
var tipValue = [];
var totalAmmount = [];
var john = {
    bill: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
    // tipValue: [],
    // totalAmmount: [],
    calcTip() {
        this.bill.forEach(function (ele, i) {
            tipValue[i] = innercalc(ele);
            totalAmmount[i] = tipValue[i] + ele;
        }); //not working code

        function innercalc(value) {
            if (value < 50)
                return value * 0.2;
            else if (value > 50 && value < 200)
                return value * 0.15;
            else if (value > 200)
                return value * 0.1;
        }
    }
}

john.calcTip();
console.log(tipValue);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="codingchallange5.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arrow function. It will not mess with `this` and everything will work as you expected:

```js
var john = {
  bill: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tipValue: [],
  totalAmmount: [],
  calcTip() {

    this.bill.forEach((ele, i) => { // replace with arrow function here
      this.tipValue[i] = innercalc(ele);
      this.totalAmmount[i] = this.tipValue[i] + ele;
    });

    function innercalc(value) {
      if (value < 50)
        return value * 0.2;
      else if (value > 50 && value < 200)
        return value * 0.15;
      else if (value > 200)
        return value * 0.1;
    }

  }
}

john.calcTip();
console.log(john.tipValue);
```

**From MDN:** An arrow function expression is a syntactically compact alternative to a regular function expression, although without its own bindings to the `this`, `arguments`, `super`, or `new.target` keywords.

Answer (score 0):

When you used **this** in function **forEach()**, it is **undefined** by default as you did not pass any reference argument. You need to pass a reference to *john* to **forEach()**!

```js
    this.bill.forEach(function (ele, i) {
            this.tipValue[i] = innercalc(ele);
            this.totalAmmount[i] = this.tipValue[i] + ele;
        }, this);
```

```
array.forEach(function(currentValue, index, arr), thisValue)
```

**thisValue**:

- Optional. A value to be passed to the function to be used as its "this" value.
- If this parameter is empty, the value "undefined" will be passed as its "this" value.

[JavaScript Array forEach() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)